# Java SQL Server connection string

Tags: java, sql-server

How can i create a java connection to an sql server located on a different server and in a different location (remote).
I am new to SQL Server, the server holding the database is 172.16.18.145 and the machine where am running the application from is 192.168.17.5

Answer (score 0):

Your JDBC url would include the server name and port. Could you please elaborate the problem you are facing

```
 String url="jdbc:db2://172.16.18.145:50007/exampledb";
            String user="db2inst1";
            String password="password";
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
```